# How can I update a JSON file from MySQL to automatically display real-time weather data in Highcharts on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts

I have a project in a web page where the final user can do a request of meteorogical data from a mysql db, the i have the python program that gets all the data every second and upload to the database, group by hour, day, etc. i want to show in the inital page the automatically the last hour data in a chart that is updating in real time.

I have a chart that recovers the last hour data from mysql but is just one request so if i want to see the last data i need to reload the page, I knwo that highcharts can do that i want from json file that is updating every second. So how can I create a script that is always running updating a json file with the new data or what alternatives did you recommend.

My actual chart is this where I get the data from a php file that do the request to my db.

```
<?php echo "var data = ".$min.";" ?>

function sortSeriesDataByName(aSeries) {
    aSeries.data.sort(function(a,b){
        return a[0] - b[0];
    });
}

var series = [{
    name: "Temperature (°C)",
    data: []
  },
  {
    name: "Humedity (%)",
    data: [],
    yAxis: 1
  }
];

data.forEach(function(dataEl) {
  series[0].data.push([
    new Date(dataEl.date).getTime(),
    Number(dataEl.temperature)
  ]);
  series[1].data.push([
    new Date(dataEl.date).getTime(),
    Number(dataEl.humidity)
  ]);
});
exporting: {
                         url: 'http://export.highcharts.com/index-utf8-encode.php'
                      }
series.forEach(sortSeriesDataByName);
Highcharts.chart('hora', {
  series: series,
  title: {
    text: 'Last hour humidity and temperature'
  },
  yAxis: [{
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
      }
    },
    {
      title: {
        text: 'Humedity (%)'
      },
      opposite: true
    }
  ],
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  }
});
```

I want to have something like this but with real data:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/

Comment: "a script that is always running updating a json file" - do you mean `setInterval()`? In the example that you linked, just change the function inside `setInterval()` to an ajax call to get your data instead of random number.